# Putty gives "Network Error: Connection time out" while connecting to raspberry pi 3 using router in windows

Tags: router, putty, raspberry-pi3

I am using D'link rouer DSL-2750U.  I have installed raspbian jessie in Rpi 3 and connected it to router. Connected my laptop to router wifi. But when i try to connect putty using the IP address of raspberrypi which i have got from router admin panel it gives connection time out error. Also i have tried to adjust keepalive seconds in putty connection setting and enabled X11 forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check if ssh is enabled in your device:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

then navigate to ssh, hit Enter and select Enable or disable ssh server. Now reboot raspberry and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Please Open you RaspberryPI terminal and run the command "sudo service ssh restart". Try connect again from putty

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who is getting a network error from Putty even all of their network settings are okay, you just follow a single step:

[image]

Just go there in <kbd>Connection</kbd> and set the time for 10 sec or more.